# C++ memory leak new and delete

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I am having difficulty finding this memory leak.

I believe it has something to do with **basin**

```
int numbasinsx(int size, double *f)
{
    int maxBasin, maxRelabel, bcnt;
    unsigned int newgene;
    int *basin, *relabel;
    int relabelcnt;

    //
    // find the basins
    //
    maxBasin = 1<<size;
    basin = new int [maxBasin];
    for (int gene=0; gene<maxBasin; gene++) basin[gene] = 0;

    bool change = true;
    bcnt = 0;
    while (change) {
        change = false;

        for (int gene=0; gene<maxBasin; gene++) {

            bool dominated = false;
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {               // for all neighbors
                newgene = gene ^ (1<<i);               // newgene is a neighbor 1 bit away

                if (f[newgene] > f[gene]) dominated = true;  // if neighbor is better mark it

                if (basin[newgene]!=0) {                                        // something to copy
                    if (f[newgene] > f[gene]) {                                // gene is dominated
                        if (basin[gene]==0 || basin[gene]<basin[newgene]) {    // if not labeled or not lowest number
                            basin[gene] = basin[newgene];                      // then label or relabel
                            change = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (f[newgene] == f[gene]) {
                        if (basin[gene]<basin[newgene]) {
                            basin[gene] = basin[newgene];
                            change = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (! dominated && basin[gene]==0) {
//                printf("max: %d %lg\n", gene, f[gene]);
                basin[gene] = ++bcnt;
                change = true;
            }
        }
    }


    //
    // relabel the basins
    //
    maxRelabel = maxBasin/2+1;
    relabel = new int [maxRelabel];
    for (int gene=0; gene<maxRelabel; gene++) relabel[gene] = 0;

    relabelcnt = 1;
    for (int gene=0; gene<maxBasin; gene++) {
        if (basin[gene]>=maxRelabel) printf("ERROR: trying to index %d into relabel array with max index of %d\n", basin[gene], maxRelabel-1);

        if (relabel[basin[gene]]==0) {
            relabel[basin[gene]] = relabelcnt++;
        }
//        printf("%d %lg %d\n", gene, f[gene], relabel[basin[gene]]);
    }
//    printf("%d\n", relabelcnt-1);

    delete basin;
    delete relabel;

    return relabelcnt-1;
}
```

I will leave the above up as to help others, but the new code with vectors is now at http://codepad.org/KiV85Brw. The vector run time is much slower than the delete[] version, and it is even segfaulting for large inputs. I am doing something wrong

Comment: Why not use a vector? No more memory leaks!

Comment: use delete[] for stuff allocated with new [] ...

Comment: [Mismatching scalar and vector new and delete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/03/66660.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you are doing unnecessary copies, as I stated in another comment. You are also initializing explicitly the elements inside a vector, which is useless, since as chris stated, those are value-initialized to 0. As for the segfault, grab a debugger and start checking your code :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `operator new[]` to allocate a bunch of bytes, then you **must** use `operator delete[]` to destroy them:

```
basin = new int [maxBasin];
//.....
delete[] basin;
```

Note that you're doing the same thing with `relabel`.

Anyway, for this kind of tasks, you should use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> basin(maxBasin), relabel(maxRelabel); // We haz no leaks
```

Comment: Awesome answer. It worked and you gave me a better solution! I am implementing with vectors now. Muchas Gracias

Comment: @RunHard, All you should need to do is change the declarations and get rid of the `new[]` and `delete` you have. You don't need to fill it with 0s, either, as the vector default-initializes the ints.

Comment: RunHard Glad it helped! @chris actually I believe elements are value-initialized, not default-initialized. If they were default initialized, then they'd contain garbage(since they're `int`s).

Comment: @mfontanini, My bad. I had the wrong word come to mind.

Comment: I am working on refactoring using vectors, and I am getting this error - error: cannot convert `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' to `int*' for argument `3' to `void mark(int, double*, int*, int, int)' ------ which leads to this line ---- if (dominated) mark(size, f, basin, gene, bcnt++); ------ It is a problem using the vector with the function expecting an integer pointer.

Comment: Had to change function as well: inline void mark(int size, double *f, std::vector<int> basin, int gene, int bcnt)

Comment: Yes, effectively, you can't implicitly convert a `std::vector` to an `int*`. Watch out, you are making unnecessary copies every time you call your function `mark`(which is most likely not what you want). You should take `std::vector`s by const reference: `..., const std::vector<int> &basin, ....`.

Comment: @chris It is now running slower and even segfaulting for large inputs.

Comment: @RunHard, In C++11, vectors have a `data()` function to get the pointer for functions that need it. Pre-C++11, try `&myVec[0]`. Of course if those are your functions, it is better to change them. Also do pass it by const reference if you can.

Answer (score 4):

`new[]` must be followed by `delete[]`, not merely `delete`.  Your code for freeing arrays `basin` and `relabel` is all wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Both `basin` and `relable` are arrays.  When you allocate an array on the heap with the **`new`** operator the syntax for deleting the array is different than the syntax for deleting a single variable.  The correct syntax is:

```
delete[] basin;
delete[] relable;
```

I believe that the code you have, as written, only deletes the first element of each array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are allocating an array, use `delete [] basin;`.
The `delete` operator is for single objects; the `delete []` is for multiple objects (arrays).

Answer (score 1):

```
   basin = new int [maxBasin];
```

with arrays you should use operator delete[]. Check also for  `relabel`.

It looks like it is a small local variable, are you sure that you want to use dynamic allocation? Why? If you have to than try unique_ptr.